# How to navigate between tabs "TabBarController" and transfer data between them?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

this code works almost as it should, but it opens a second window on top of the main one, and not separately. How do I programmatically navigate to another view controller?

```
let tableVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SaveTableViewController") as! SaveTableViewController 
tableVC.titleText = alert.textFields![0].text ?? "Test" 
tableVC.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
 //self.tabBarController?.showDetailViewController(tableVC, sender: self)
 //self.present(tableVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `tabBarController` have a `viewControllers` array. If you want to show a specific ViewController programmatically you could set the `selectedViewController` attribute of your `tabBarController` to an element out of the `viewControllers` array...
For more detail: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621172-selectedviewcontroller